# Test meta data with CodeceptJs + Puppeteer

Tags: e2e-testing, codeceptjs

I can't seem to find anything about this in the official documents or anywhere,
I would like to test if my website have all the right meta tags and OG data in the header.

Is this possible with CodeceptJs and Puppeteer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [seeElementInDOM](https://codecept.io/helpers/Puppeteer/#seeelementindom) method to find elements in DOM.

Or you can just grab page HTML source with [grabSource](https://codecept.io/helpers/Puppeteer/#grabsource) and check meta tags as string containing in that source

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using a helper

```
class CustomHelper extends Helper {

  async getPageOGTitle() {
    const page = this.helpers['Puppeteer'].page;
    const description = await page.$eval(
      "head > meta[property='og:title']",
      element => element.content
    );
    return description;
  }

}
```

and then using it in my test

```
Scenario('Page Have OG title', async I => {
  const OGTitle = await I.getPageOGTitle();
  console.log(OGTitle);
});
```